# How could I request urls just changes last part of url

Tags: python, scrapy

In spider, I just want to request URLs that have one rule.

URLs list :

1. [www.example.com/bread/coffee/A](http://www.example.com/bread/coffee/A)
2. [www.example.com/bread/coffee/B](http://www.example.com/bread/coffee/B)
3. [www.example.com/bread/coffee/C](http://www.example.com/bread/coffee/C)
4. [www.example.com/bread/coffee/D](http://www.example.com/bread/coffee/D)

so start_request is [www.example.com/bread/coffee/A](http://www.example.com/bread/coffee/A)
and then what gonna have to do in def parse ??

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'exmple.com'
    start_urls = [www.example.com/bread/coffee/A]
    
    def parse(self, response):
        ???
        yield ???
```

a little hint will appreciate

Answer (score 1):

you  can use code like this:

```py
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'exmple.com'
    start_urls = ['www.example.com/bread/coffee/A']

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'www.example.com/bread/coffee/A',
            'www.example.com/bread/coffee/B',
            'www.example.com/bread/coffee/C',
            'www.example.com/bread/coffee/D'
        ]

        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        # find what you need
        yield # your item/dict
```

also, make sure your url(s) has correct format, they should contains `http` or `https`

aslo you can use `string` module to generate your urls

```
import string
def start_requests(self):
        url = 'www.example.com/bread/coffee/{}'
        for l in string.ascii_uppercase:
            url = url.format(l)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: thank you for your help. but I need some more. actually Not just A,B,C,D the list of last URL are in database(but they are still strings). So I think i can use second. maybe base_url='www.example.com/bread/coffe/      for lastURL in urlList    url = base_url.urljoin~~   something.